# ClassCastException in Espresso test with Dagger 2 after upgrading to Android Gradle 2.2.0 plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, gradle-dependencies

Since updating to the Android 2.2.0 Gradle plugin, my Espresso tests have started failing with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app.debug/com.myapp.app.conversation.ConversationActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.app.conversation.data.SqlMessageStore cannot be cast to com.myapp.app.auth.UserScopedAccountStore
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.app.conversation.data.SqlMessageStore cannot be cast to com.myapp.app.auth.UserScopedAccountStore
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_UserScopedAccountStoreFactory.get(UserModule_UserScopedAccountStoreFactory.java:30)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_UserScopedAccountStoreFactory.get(UserModule_UserScopedAccountStoreFactory.java:10)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_TokenInterceptorFactory.get(UserModule_TokenInterceptorFactory.java:30)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_TokenInterceptorFactory.get(UserModule_TokenInterceptorFactory.java:10)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_AuthedOkHttpClientFactory.get(UserModule_AuthedOkHttpClientFactory.java:30)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_AuthedOkHttpClientFactory.get(UserModule_AuthedOkHttpClientFactory.java:10)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_HipChatClientFactory.get(UserModule_HipChatClientFactory.java:81)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_HipChatClientFactory.get(UserModule_HipChatClientFactory.java:17)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_LogoutFactory.get(UserModule_LogoutFactory.java:29)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_LogoutFactory.get(UserModule_LogoutFactory.java:10)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_SignedInPresenterFactory.get(UserModule_SignedInPresenterFactory.java:69)
at com.myapp.app.di.module.UserModule_SignedInPresenterFactory.get(UserModule_SignedInPresenterFactory.java:16)
at com.myapp.app.BaseSignedInActivity_MembersInjector.injectPresenter(BaseSignedInActivity_MembersInjector.java:44)
at com.myapp.app.conversation.ConversationActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(ConversationActivity_MembersInjector.java:40)
at com.myapp.app.conversation.ConversationActivity_MembersInjector.injectMembers(ConversationActivity_MembersInjector.java:9)
at com.myapp.app.di.DaggerUserComponent.inject(DaggerUserComponent.java:993)
at com.myapp.app.conversation.ConversationActivity.inject(ConversationActivity.java:149)
at com.myapp.app.BaseSignedInActivity.onCreate(BaseSignedInActivity.java:59)
at com.myapp.app.conversation.ConversationActivity.onCreate(ConversationActivity.java:57)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:532)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
... 10 more
```

Running the app works completely fine. Changing this back to the Android 2.1.3 Gradle plugin fixes the espresso problems (with no other changes). I've attempted cleaning, rebuilding, and restarting the gradle daemon to no avail. I also tried updating to 2.2.1 and bumping to the latest Dagger 2 version (2.7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible you have duplicate dependencies? Try using `compileOnly` instead of `compile` for test dependencies.

Comment: Turns out we had a transitive dependency for a shared-test module which resulted in duplicated classes in our test apk and app apk. For whatever reason, this behavior changed going from 2.1.3 to 2.2.0. It should also be noted this had absolutely nothing to do with Dagger 2 :)